# Keep the navigation bar elements static whether the page has a scrollbar or not

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar at the top of my site. The problem is the navigation bar flinches in when when one of the pages have scrollbar. Which is very uncomfortable to look at when routing from one page to another. How to change the code so that the navigation bar seems always static whether the page has scrollbar or not.

One way to do this is to hide scrollbar in the `body` tag and write custom `css` for every component. But that's not an ideal solution.

Here is my `css` for navigation bar.

```css
.navigation-bar {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 4.5vw;
    background: white;
    z-index: 121;
}

.nav {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0;

}

.nav-item {
    padding: 0 1.75vw;
    margin: 0 0.5vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav-item a {
    margin: auto 0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #515F66;
}


.nav-pad {
    align-self: center;
}

.active-nav {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #25C27A;
}


.active-nav a{
    color: #25C27A;
}

.nav-item:hover a{
    color: #25C27A;
}
```

And here is the `html`

```html
<div class='navigation-bar box-shadow'>
    <div class='col-sm-1 text-center nav-pad'>
        <div src={api_icon} className='img-fluid' alt="icon" />
    </div>

    <div class='col-sm-3 title-text nav-pad' />
        Title
    </div>

    <div class='nav-bar'>
        <div class='nav-item active-nav' href='/'>
            Home
        </div>
        <div class='nav-item' href='/payment'>
             Usage History 
        </div>
        <div class='nav-item' href='/pricing'>
          Pricing
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-sm-3 py-auto nav-pad'>
        username
    </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: Can you please describe you problem a little bit more or may be simple html fiddle would be good without react for understanding your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the scroll of the body and add scroll to div below your navbar.
For example, suppose the DOM that your react app generates is of the form:

```
<body>
    <nav>one two three</nav> // let the height be fixed (60px say)
    <div class="scroll">
      content apart from the navbar
    </div>
</body>
```

Let's remove the scroll from `body` and add scroll to `.scroll` div.

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px); // as the height of navbar is 60px
  overflow: auto;
}
```

See the complete code snippet below.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 60px;
  background: skyblue;
}

.scroll {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <nav>this is the fixed navbar</nav>
    <div class="scroll">
      <p>
        scroll element
      </p>
      <p>
        scroll element
      </p>
      <p>
        scroll element
      </p>
      <p>
        scroll element
      </p>
      <p>
        scroll element
      </p>
      <p>
        scroll element
      </p>
      <p>
        scroll element
      </p>
      <p>
        scroll element
      </p><p>
        scroll element
      </p>
      <p>
        scroll element
      </p><p>
        scroll element
      </p><p>
        scroll element
      </p><p>
        scroll element
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have already done that in the current version. Apparently my team lead is not totally convinced with the solution.

Comment: well thanks to your answer I finally understood what I was doing wrong.
All I needed to do was render the navigation bar in a parent component which will inherit other components in different routes. Then using css class `scroll` made it work.